# How do I remove the first object from an array of objects that is inside a useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects within a useState hook, it looks something like this:

```
const[list,setList] = useState(null)

function x() {

setList([
{id:1,name:a},
{id:2,name:b},
{id:3,name:c},
]
}
```

I want to create a function that will delete a certain amount of these objects from the begining of the array. For example if I were to run the function delete(2), it would delete the first two objects in the array. Leaving list equal to only [{id:3,name:c}]

Comment: What did you try to achieve this? Did you encounter any error?

Comment: Sorry I miss wrote the title, I tried using this method    setList(list.filter(item => item.id!== 1)); but it didn't seem to work for me, and I couldn't figure out how to get it to work for multiple objects

Comment: I made simple JavaScript function. setList(arr), and deleteItem() will work for you.
Please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
let arr = [
{id:1,name:"e"},
{id:2,name:"wd"},
{id:3,name:"das"},
]
  


function deleteItem(index){
  return arr.filter(ele=>ele.id>2);
}
console.log(deleteItem(2))
```

It would be help. you can use `array.filter()` function easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wish to remove elements from the beginning of the array you could use the `shift()` function. The `shift()` removes only the first element of an array. Using this function you could build something like this:

```
let arr = [
{id:1,name:"e"},
{id:2,name:"wd"},
{id:3,name:"das"},
] 

const removeFirstElements = (numberOfElements) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
         arr.shift();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

You can then take the result of this function and set it in your list.

```
const filteredArr = removeFirstElements(2);
// filteredArr contains [{id:3,name:"das"}]
setList(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use this function, you can call it with the desired number of items to delete:

```
function deleteFromBeginning(count) {
  setList(prevList => prevList.slice(count))
}
```

This will remove the first two items from the list.

```
deleteFromBeginning(2);
```